# Профайлер ModX Revo ну и другой способ дебаггинга...

Tags: modx, php

Помогите найти нормальный профайлер для ModX - я новичек не могу найти упоминание о дебаггинге или дебаг моде в ModX. То что он умеет ошибки PHP выводить - это не подходит..
Нужно что то на подобии Trace-like как в CI или Yii..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А чем не устраивает ChromePHP подключается через инклуд.

Comment: а можете рассказать по подробнее? а то с встроенным в браузер расширением в первые работать буду... может мало знаю просто еще для своего опыта...

Comment: http://modx.im/blog/addons/244.html вот отличный Дебагер

Comment: Гениально! это то что нужно - только настроить бы еще...